# NUnit SetUpFixture attribute equivalent in xUnit?

Tags: nunit, xunit.net

In nUnit, SetUpFixture allowed me to run some code before any tests. Is there anything like that when using xUnit?

---

[From nUnit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4):

> This is the attribute that marks a class that contains the one-time setup or teardown methods for all the test fixtures under a given namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xUnit's [comparison table](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons&referringTitle=Home) shows that where you would use `[TestFixtureSetUp]` in NUnit, you make your test fixture class implement `IUseFixture<T>`.

---

If `[TestFixtureSetUp]` isn't the attribute you're looking for, then the header at the beginning of the compatibility table indicates that there is no equivalent:

> Note: any testing framework attributes that are not in this list have no corresponding attribute in xUnit.net.

Comment: I guess that one is per fixture. I need one that is per whole assembly.

Comment: Workaround would do. And I read that xUnit is quite extensible. Just thinking - can't be that no one have faced this problem.

Comment: +1d - xUnit Test Patterns (and extensive use of xUnit.net) says you use `IUseFixture<TFixture>` and let the impl of the fixture class set up the appropriate prerequisites, treating the fact that you only want to do it once per assembly as an optimisation within the fixture (maybe cache stuff in a static or whatever is appropriate). If you want to do very wacky stuff, look at a custom runner-class a la the SubSpec sample (download full source - iits quite short)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but for anyone that comes looking, you can create a base fixture class which implements IClassFixture. Your test fixtures can all inherit from this base class.

You could inject singleton classes to this base class if you need stuff to run assembly wide.

```
internal abstract class TestFixtureBase : IClassFixture<TestApplicationFactory>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    protected TestFixtureBase(TestApplicationFactory factory)
    {
    //...
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
    }

    public Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```