# Is there a nunit setup attribute equivalent that could be added for some tests in xunit?

Tags: nunit, xunit

In NUnit when I had to do the setup for some tests I would use `[Setup]` Attribute.

Now in xUnit there are TextFixtures but they are only run before each test or run before all tests once, but there's no option to run it for some but not all tests.

This question is purely for my personal educational purposes.

Above can be easily solved by simply making a `SetUp()` method and just calling it inside the tests where it is needed, but I was wondering if there was a 'proper' way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NUnit SetUpFixture attribute equivalent in xUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986143/nunit-setupfixture-attribute-equivalent-in-xunit)

Comment: @LexLi so the answer is basically no.